# Hide fields from a view

Tags: views

I am not sure how to explain this as I have very little experience with Drupal. I built a site with Drupal 7 and now I am trying to recreate it in Drupal 8. I have a problem with the Content area.

I have set up a view that looks like this.
[image]

The arrow points to a title name link.

When I click the link, I want to see additional detail not shown in the view. This works. However, there is as an additional view that looks like a “teaser” view that I do not want to be displayed. The area at the top in the rectangle I want and is part of the “Entity View (Content) with a category of Chaos Tools. The bottom part near the x is the teaser part and is a duplicate of the top part I don’t want. How can I remove the bottom part?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

man. Have you solved yet? There's this custom module that even someone with basics of programming could do. But it is not perfect, you will have to make an extra view and stuff... https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/removing-duplicate-content-across-multiple-drupal-views